# ¿Cómo compartir google sheet con la barra de menus deshabilitada u oculta?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una google sheet para compartir con usuarios de mi trabajo cumpliendo con:

1. Compartirla usando los correos electrónicos
2. Dar acceso de edición solo a un rango de celdas (con validación de datos activada) para que introduzcan datos
3. Bloquear el acceso a la barra de menu para evitar que modifiquen la hoja y la validación de datos

1 y 2 ya están resueltos pero no encuentro una forma de dar acceso a la google sheet vía mail y al mismo tiempo bloqueando u ocultando la barra de menús. Se puede compartir agregando "?rm=minimal" al final de la url, pero incumpliendo con 1) Compartirla usando los correos electrónicos.

He buscado algún script que oculte o bloquee la barra de menus al abrir la hoja pero sin suerte.

¿Alguna idea?