# Insertar una Google Sheet en mi página WEB y MANIPULARLA

Tags: html, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Mi problema es el siguiente:

- Quiero literalmente extraer una hoja de calculo de Google Sheet y modificarla como si estuviese ahí.
  Para que se entienda más: Es como un video de Youtube, que cuando se coloca en una página web, tenés todas las opciones disponibles como si lo estuvieses viendo de youtube.

Entiendo perfectamente como publicar los datos de una hoja de cálculo en mi página web.
También sé que hay una API de Google Sheets.
El tema es que tendría que agregar todas las funciones manualmente y no es la idea recrear un Google Sheet, sino que, utilizarlo desde una parte de mi página web.

Comment: Google Sheets permite generar el iframe pa embeber un HTML con el contenido de la hoja pero **no permite** editar en vivo.

Comment: @Alfabravo Sí lo permite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa una etiqueta `iframe` y al atributo src asígnale el URL  de tu hoja de cálculo (para editar debe terminar en `/edit`).

```html
<iframe src="url_de_tu_spreadsheet"></iframe>
```

Para ocultar el encabezado, los menús y la barra lateral agrega al URL de la hoja de cálculo un query-string con el parámetro `rm=minimal`

```html
<iframe src="url_de_tu_spreadsheet?rm=minimal"></iframe>
```

Si deseas especificar la hoja a mostrar, por ejemplo `#gid=0` (hash), el query-string debe indicarse primero, y el hash al final

```html
<iframe src="url_de_tu_spreadsheet?rm=minimal#gid=0"></iframe>
```

**Relacionado**

*Internos*

- [¿Cómo compartir google sheet con la barra de menus deshabilitada u oculta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/529076/65)

*Externos*

- [Embed only cells from Google Spreadsheet and not application header](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/30644/88163)
- [Google sheet embed URL documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23446449/1595451)
- [How to embed specific editable cells from a google sheet into a site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65678620/1595451)

Comment: Sería la URL que uno obtiene cuando elige la opción _Compartir_ de la hoja de cálculo? Habría que configurarle permisos para que cualquiera la pueda editar o algo, ¿verdad?

Comment: @Alfabravo Puedes tomar la URL directamente del navegador, de la opción Compartir entre otros lugares... lo de configuración de permisos es igual que acceder la hoja de cálculo usando directamente su URL.

Comment: Me funciona perfecto para la primer idea que tenía. Muchas gracias!
Me surge un problema para agregar parametros y poder editar.
Por ejemplo con el siguiente link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ID}/edit#gid=0
No sé como agregar el header de rm=minimal a la vez.

Comment: @MiqueasGentile agregué un ejemplo sobre cómo incluir `#gid=0`.  Te sugiero dedicar tiempo  a familiarizarte términos como URL, URI, query string (cadena de búsqueda), hash (fragmento de URI). Si requieres mayor orientación publica una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Rubén rm=minimal me sirve como nos señalas para ocultar una encabezados, menús, barra, pero no los identificadores de filas (1,2,3,4,5...) y columnas (A,B,C,D,E....), ¿hay un parámetro que me permita ocultarlas para presentar el contenido de la tabla sin ello?